# Excel Combo Box -- how to validate input (not data validation list)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, data-validation

I'm trying to use Active X Combo boxes instead of Validation Lists for some dropdown menus in Excel, because it's more apparent they are drop-down selections (arrow icon appears next to it).

However even if 'match required' is set to true, I receive no error whatsoever if I enter any old garbage. Even if the list is a selection of 3-4 cells.

How do I prevent the behavior of entering any old garbage into the combo box when there is a definitive list to select from?

Answer (score 0):

The MatchRequired property of the Active X Combo box is really only effective when the object is used as part of a User Form, and not embedded in a worksheet.

For an embedded control you'll need a VBA function to handle data validation. Enabling the 'Design Mode' button on the Developer tab will let you double-click the object to create a empty Change event function where you can add your validation code.